# Is there a way to get the fee of a Chainlink Automation job before it happens? Like CCIP's getFee?

Tags: chainlink

I have a contract that uses Chainlink Log Trigger Automation and I want to be able to get the exact fee for the Automation before it happens.

The user pays in LINK to use the contract and the transaction involves the use of Log Trigger Automation. The user should pay the exact fee in LINK, rather than a slightly more, general amount.

This is the line in the function where funds are added to the automation consumer contract. The `linkAutomationPayment` is provided by the user when they call the function.

```
i_automationConsumer.addFunds(i_subId, uint96(linkAutomationPayment));
```

The `uint96(linkAutomationPayment)` should be the exact amount required for the `checkLog` and `performUpkeep` functions to successfully work - with the user's provided input. (The user provides an address as a parameter, an event is emitted based on that address, then data from that event is used in `checkLog` and `performUpkeep`).

CCIP has a `getFee` function that allows users to get the fee for a transaction based on its parameters before it happens, and something like that would be ideal for Automation. Is there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chainlink Automation does not have that exact functionality yet. What you can do is utilize the https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/automation/v2_1/KeeperRegistryLogicB2_1.sol#L458-L460 function which is the minimum balance required for an Upkeep to execute, but it is not the exact amount the Job will cost.